# error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 MiB

Tags: git, clone, https, vmware-workstation

I am trying to install [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64)  toolchain in ubuntu 14.04 running on vmware
My computer is a part of a network and it is configured as remote access.
This error is showing up:

```
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools
Cloning into 'tools'...
remote: Counting objects: 25343, done.
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 MiB | 109.00 KiB/s   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I tried to disable avira antivirus and firewall but bo luck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly

Comment: i tried this git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git

Comment: and this show up:$: command not found

Comment: Read other answers ;)